# Estimating time to solve based on skill and difficulty

Tags: probability-distributions, estimation

My question may be a bit too straight forward for this section but I would like to have some incentives here, as I feel like I am missing something. 
Consider the following simple problem: you give some students a problem to solve. You give a score to this problem which expresses its difficulty. Let's note this difficulty $\delta$. Each student has also a skill score $\lambda$, attached.

The question is the following: how can you accurately estimate the time a student with a particular skill is going to take to solve a problem of a particular difficulty? I have tried to construct a probability distribution based on these two parameters (Weibull) an to randomly select a solving time in this distribution. However it doesnt suit well, as some very low skill students may be able to solve a very difficult problem very fast. It also brings a problem when $\lambda = \delta$.

I am not able to find a reliable solution to this, even if I believe that it should not be so hard. If you have any clue, I would appreciate.

edit: This problem is related to Item Response Theory, I will then investigate here.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a research question actually. I found the following interesting paper: https://www.fi.muni.cz/~xpelanek/publications/sofsem12.pdf, will work on that

Comment: I'd be very interested to figure out how you measure the difficulty and the students skill in an objective way, what is the methodology there?

Comment: Actually I twisted my problem, because it is not related to students and I don't need to estimate this skill level / difficulty values. Nonetheless, it opens new way to my research so its very interesting. It seems to be classical statistical estimations using maximum likelihood or SVD though.